# BuddyPress - Importing Member Profile Photos (Avatars) from CSV

Tags: wordpress, import, profile, buddypress, avatar

We have 260 users to import. On the old site they were created as a custom post type, I've managed to import these as users on the new site using a CSV so they are all now set up as BuddyPress members, but I want to avoid having to log in as each of them and set the profile photos manually.

I believe BP stores these in the Uploads folder then in folders corresponding to the user ID, but it presumably needs to create a reference for them in the database and also has to crop them. I can fill a column with all the image URLs on the old site, along with user IDs, just need a script or plugin to do the rest.

Comment: BP does not use a db reference for user or group avatars.

Comment: @shanebp does that mean I can just place the avatar images in the right folders and it will pick them up?

Comment: No. They need the correct names.  Upload an avatar for a member and check the resulting imgs.